# Querying across 7 tables with values from one table as column headings in retured result

Tags: mysql

I am working with MySQL version 5.6.39.

I have the following ERD for an application I'm working on.

[image]

I am trying to write some SQL that will give me this:

[image]

Basically, for a given account reference, between the journey start and end, I wish to select the AccelerationScore, BreakingScore, CorneringScore, SpeedingScore and DrivingScore.

[**Here's an MCVE**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bQMFqm9an5CEd3RC76LpYG/1).

Here is the **code** I have:

```
SELECT
    v.VehicleReference,
    j.EndDateTime,
    COUNT(sp.SpeedingEventId) AS SpeedingCount
FROM
    AccountAndDevices.Journey j
INNER JOIN
    AccountAndDevices.Device d ON j.DeviceId = d.DeviceId
INNER JOIN
    AccountAndDevices.Vehicle v ON d.VehicleId = v.VehicleId
INNER JOIN
    AccountAndDevices.Account a ON a.AccountId = v.AccountId
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        AccountAndDevices.SpeedingEvent sp On j.DeviceId = sp.DeviceId
    AND
        sp.DateTime BETWEEN j.StartDateTime AND j.EndDateTime
WHERE
        a.AccountReference = 'TestUser03@example.com'
    AND
        JourneyId =
            (SELECT
                JourneyId
            FROM
                AccountAndDevices.Journey j
            INNER JOIN
                AccountAndDevices.Device d ON j.DeviceId = d.DeviceId
            INNER JOIN
                AccountAndDevices.Vehicle v ON d.VehicleId = v.VehicleId
            INNER JOIN
                AccountAndDevices.Account a ON a.AccountId = v.AccountId
            WHERE
                    a.AccountReference = 'TestUser03@example.com'
                AND
                    j.EndDateTime <= NOW()
            ORDER BY
                j.EndDateTime
            DESC
            LIMIT
                1)
GROUP BY
    v.VehicleReference,
    j.EndDateTime;
```

This gets me close, but it is missing all the scores, and I am struggling to get the scores out of the JourneyScores table and have their types (in ScoreType table) as column headings.

Comment: Please frame SQL questions with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya does this count? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bQMFqm9an5CEd3RC76LpYG/0

Comment: Please add some data to the fiddle. Also add this fiddle link to the question. Also, elaborate further on logic behind the expected output.

Comment: How does one do that? Do I simply write insert statements for each table and run them?

Comment: yes. here is an example fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ma7MhufseHxEXLfxhCtGbZ/3

Comment: Thanks, added MCVE to the updated question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185011/discussion-between-j86-and-madhur-bhaiya).